# Is there a C++ function for make a png from a dot language string?

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz

I already wrote a simulator which uses the Boost library's graph. I know I can make a dot language from it, but how can I make an image from this string?
I have graphviz but I could not find the function to make a png file.

Afterwards, I want show it on a Qgraphicsview. After this I would like to show information on a Label about an edge when I click on it.

The most important part is to make this png. It is not a problem if I cannot click on it (I make other options to choose an edge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several graphviz libraries. [cgraph](https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf), for example, has functions to construct a graph from a dot description in a string and then render it into a buffer.